# How do I combine all objects after a certain index in an array to the same object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

Good day, I hope someone can help.

I have an array of objects that looks like this that I'm looking to reduce the objects a little:

```
[
    {
        "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
        "countryCode": "BE",
        "totalReclaimPotential": 2506.0360930000006
    },
    {
        "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
        "countryCode": "DK",
        "totalReclaimPotential": 1932.5224279999995
    },
    {
        "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
        "countryCode": "PT",
        "totalReclaimPotential": 586.8
    },
    {
        "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
        "countryCode": "NL",
        "totalReclaimPotential": 569.1673320000001
    },
    {
        "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
        "countryCode": "CH",
        "totalReclaimPotential": 544.3347689999999
    },
    {
        "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
        "countryCode": "ES",
        "totalReclaimPotential": 453.127841
    },
    {
        "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
        "countryCode": "KR",
        "totalReclaimPotential": 448.640522
    },
    {
        "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
        "countryCode": "TW",
        "totalReclaimPotential": 204.25425299999998
    },
]
```

What I'm trying to do is combine all the objects after index 3 to the same object. It should look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
        "countryCode": "BE",
        "totalReclaimPotential": 2506.0360930000006
    },
    {
        "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
        "countryCode": "DK",
        "totalReclaimPotential": 1932.5224279999995
    },
    {
        "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
        "countryCode": "PT",
        "totalReclaimPotential": 586.8
    },
    {
        "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
        "countryCode": "NL",
        "totalReclaimPotential": 569.1673320000001
    },
    {
        "entityName": "Other Entities",
        "countryCode": "",
        "totalReclaimPotential": <Total of all merged objects>
    },
    
]
```

How can I achieve this using Angular/Typescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [{
    "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
    "countryCode": "BE",
    "totalReclaimPotential": 2506.0360930000006
  },
  {
    "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
    "countryCode": "DK",
    "totalReclaimPotential": 1932.5224279999995
  },
  {
    "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
    "countryCode": "PT",
    "totalReclaimPotential": 586.8
  },
  {
    "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
    "countryCode": "NL",
    "totalReclaimPotential": 569.1673320000001
  },
  {
    "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
    "countryCode": "CH",
    "totalReclaimPotential": 544.3347689999999
  },
  {
    "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
    "countryCode": "ES",
    "totalReclaimPotential": 453.127841
  },
  {
    "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
    "countryCode": "KR",
    "totalReclaimPotential": 448.640522
  },
  {
    "entityName": "0015J00000BUWbHQAX",
    "countryCode": "TW",
    "totalReclaimPotential": 204.25425299999998
  },
]

const result = data.slice(0, 4).concat(data.slice(4).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc.totalReclaimPotential += cur.totalReclaimPotential;
  return acc;
}, {
  entityName: "Other Entities",
  countryCode: "",
  totalReclaimPotential: 0
}));

console.log('result:', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let shortenArrToLength = 4;
let total = 0;
values.map((obj, index) => {
    if(index < shortenArrToLength) {
        return;
    }
    total += obj['totalReclaimPotential'];
})

values.length = shortenArrToLength;
values.push({
    "entityName": "Other Entities",
    "countryCode": "",
    "totalReclaimPotential": total
})
console.log(values);
```

Comment: This solution also works as the below one does